# Image recognition model prediction always the same for unseen images

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, image-recognition, image-classification

I'm working on an image recognition project with a self-created dataset that contains 563 files belonging to 2 classes. I split the dataset into training and validation sets with 395 images in training and 168 images in validation set.

---

I trained a convolutional neural network using the following model:

```
# creating datagen object
base_dir = '/content/dataset/emotional_people'
train_data_gen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1/255, validation_split=0.3)
val_data_gen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1/255, validation_split = 0.3)

train_data = train_data_gen.flow_from_directory(base_dir,
                                                target_size = (256,256),
                                                class_mode = 'binary',
                                                subset = 'training',
                                                batch_size = 32)

val_data = val_data_gen.flow_from_directory(base_dir,
                                            target_size = (256,256),
                                            class_mode = 'binary',
                                            subset = 'validation',
                                            batch_size = 32)


# Data augmentation
data_augmentation = keras.Sequential([
    layers.RandomFlip("horizontal", input_shape=(256,256,3)),
    layers.RandomFlip("vertical", input_shape=(256,256,3)),
    layers.RandomRotation(0.1),
    layers.RandomZoom(0.1)])

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(16, (3,3), 1, activation='relu', input_shape=(256,256,3)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D())
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3,3), 1, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D())
model.add(Conv2D(16, (3,3), 1, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D())
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile('adam', loss=tf.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(), metrics=['accuracy'])

hist = model.fit(train_data, epochs=50, validation_data=val_data)`
```

---

During training, the model achieved a training accuracy of 0.9796 and a validation accuracy of 0.7143. However, when I use the model to predict on unseen images, the prediction value is always the same. I've tried several images, but the model always predicts the same value.

Can anyone help me understand why this is happening and how I can fix it? I'd appreciate any suggestions or insights you can provide. Thank you!

---

I did try different model architectue. The new model predicted new values but they seem to be almost same. I have tried different validation splits. But it does not work. I have tried data augmentation, by random rotation and random zoom. But still does not work.

Comment: How do you predict them? You need to add your codes for that. To me, you might be forgetting to normalize your images.

Comment: You are right. I have added the code lines in the original question now.

Answer (score 0):

Augument the data before feeding to the model, Use the below DataGenerator It will augument the image during the image loading.

```
train_data = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1.0/255.0,
    validation_split=0.3,
    rotation_range=5,
    shear_range=0.3,
    zoom_range=0.3,
    width_shift_range=0.05,
    height_shift_range=0.05,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    vertical_flip=True,
)
```

It will helps to train with high efficience and robustness